# Shockley Equation, 1N4001 and 1N4003

Tags: diodes

[image: Diodes with Voltage-current relation]

The x-axis is the current and y-axis is the voltage across the diodes

I am trying to find out with one of these lines is 1N4001 and which one is 1N4003. My intuition tells me that blue one is 1N4001, because it is heavily doped (blockage current is 50V) and the other one is naturally 1N4003 (blockage current 200V).

Comment: You cannot distinguish the 1N4001 and 1N4003 from eachother this way. The difference in forward voltage is too small to conclude anything. Take 10 different 1N4001 and measure this curve. You will get more variation between those 10 diodes then what you see here. To tell the difference you will have to test the breakdown voltage with the chance that both have a Vb > 200 V so you would still know nothing.

Comment: Often manufacturers just make one type, like 1N4007. Then they test these diodes. The ones which break down below 200 V will be 1N4001, ones that make 250 V: 1N4002, above 250 V: 1N4003 etc. Making all separate 1N4001, 1N4003 is too expensive, making only one type is cheaper.

Comment: I see, I felt like I would need more data to distinguish them both, but the TA told me maybe I could work it out somehow. I know measurements vary a lot and two lines are in no way data that can be analysed, but if we were to assume that these are absolute values with no variation, would it still be impossible to make a decision?

Comment: No, I do not think so. You assume that the diodes have different doping profiles which I doubt they do. The only difference between the diodes is their breakdown voltage. You can confirm this by looking at the datasheet. So the only way you could possibly distinguish between the two is their breakdown voltage which might not even be different. Only the 1N4003 is **guaranteed** to have a higher breakdown. It is still possible you have a "lucky" 1N4001 with an even higher breakdown.

Comment: **I challenge the basic question.**  There is no reliable and repeatable way to "measure" what part number is printed on the diode.  The ONLY reliable method is to actually read the numbers optically.  Now if you had asked "how can I measure the difference between a 50V diode and a 200V diode, then the discussion would be different.

Comment: I agree generally with what has been said-but note that with some families of Schottky diodes the differences can be more significant- although this also seems to be manufacturer dependant. 1N581x is 1A Schottky. The low voltage parts may have usefully lower Vf than higher voltage Lower and higher is relative and here afair the differences were with 20 30 40V parts. (1N5817-8-9). The difference is perhaps 0.2V best case But at say 5V that's around 4% more efficiency - which can be useful with eg buck converters operating at around 90% efficiency- so a few more percent is welcome.

Comment: @Andyaka Little secret was that it was about 6am and I'd not been to sleep (processing photos from a night market and street Christmas lights display) and 1N581x series transmogrified in brain to too too familiar 1N481x range). Deleted and reposted with correction. Ta muchly.

Answer (score 1):

The 1N4001 - 1N4007 are all the same diodes. http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds28002.pdf

Since all the characteristics are the same, the manufacturer will simply select/test the diodes to meet a range of specifications. Those that have higher leakage or break over voltage become lower range diodes. There will be differences in the manufacturers line, but they would invariably want to produce consistent results from a single build process. This plays out in much the same way the as the production of large scale chips such as microprocessors, where the power and clock rating of Individual die will vary with it's position on the silicon wafer.

You'd be better to measure the high reverse voltage leakage current as a comparison characteristics, but even here it likely won't be possible to identify individual voltage ratings.

Comment: It used to be that the higher voltage members of the 1N4001-7 family were implemented differently with a PIN structure rather than a PN structure - this was often exploited to use the diode as an RF switch.  This may have changed over the decades that the 1N4007 has been around.

Comment: You may be right @Kevin White. There definitely seems to be at least a batching (perhaps only scribing) change as the higher voltage versions have less junction capacitance. Perhaps the 1N4002 - 1N4004 are produced differently to the 1N4005 - 1N4007 ....but for the OP's question it would still seem impossible to tell the difference between a 1N4001 and a 1N4003 from the forward voltage characteristics.  ...LoL you are absolutely right about their use at RF,  I've actually seen 1N4007's used for fine tuning (10-20 pF range) at very low voltages.

Comment: I agree completely

Answer (score 1):

The incremental or ESR of all diodes is directly related to chip size and necessary thermal resistance to optimize power dissipation for any given diode, LED, Zener, or rectifier. The same is [true for Capacitors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17574%20esr) but is more diverse since dielectrics are poor thermal conductors.

ESR is always inversely related to the thermal power limit of the package, Pd  in an optimum design. The relationship is ESR= k/Pd where k =1 for most products and is ~0.5 in the best chip designs.

The variance on ESR has no sensitivity in semiconductor dielectric since the conductor size & interface property dominates the result .  Sensitivity with voltage ratings affects Caps ESR with high R_thermal, but not Semi's with low Rth.

**The tolerances of the epitaxial wafer are what defines the min/typ/max for all diode Vf at rated current.**  This is due to \$ESR=\Delta V/\Delta I\$  Within a large epi-wafer, I have seen results for ESR << 1% yet between all wafers for same part number more than 100~300% or 3:1 ratio in ESR unless binned.

High efficacy power LEDs have tighter tolerances and newer chips may enjoy 50% tolerance whereas in a matrix on the same chip with LEDs' in parallel/series arrays matching is closer to 0.1 for ESR typically (estimate).  This always confuses some who say you can't do that. ( Put LED's in parallel ) And the truth is yes and no, it depends on ESR tolerance.

All specs are given at 25'C and Shockley NTC effects apply to all BJT's and Diodes alike.

Looking at your curve from 0.85 to 0.9V the rise in current is 200mA thus ESR @25'C = 0.05V/0.2A = 0.25Ω. For a package rated at 1A @1V or 1W, there is no package Pd rating, but 1 expect 0.5Ω to 1Ω if kept cool at 25'C which requires, significant thermal heatsink clamp around body.  No wonder they are OBSOLETE for new design with preference given to SMD diodes.